# what is the process of binding c library in dart using ffi?

Tags: c, dart, ffi

Say I need to use some c library in dart (specifically lua) - then I have to bind functions in c library to dart using dart's ffi. Am I correct thinking that I will then also have to implement all of the libraries' structures in dart? I'm quite new to ffi and dart.

Background: we have a gui program written in c, that runs functions in lua when some event happens. We are evaluating the possibility to rewrite it using flutter, which uses dart and run those lua scripts via lua library and dart's ffi. It was relatively easy to run them from c code, since lua is written in c, but I'm not sure if my reasoning is correct regarding dart or I'm missing something. Or is there some other option?

Comment: The main problem with using Lua through an FFI: many of its "functions" are really just C macros defined in `lua.h`, so they can't be used through any FFI. You would have to implement those manually in the host language (Which shouldn't be too difficult, if you just copy-translate the macro)

Comment: Thanks. Is that because there is nothing to call in resulting binary since the "calls" of macros in source code are substituted with the code they refer to in the binary? But i checked it right now and it seems that the API is indeed real functions and probably only some helper "functions" are macros - so it seems it should be possible, since I probably won't call those helper functions directly. And probably it wouldn't be good idea from authors of lua to write its API as macros.

Comment: Yes, you're right. It's mostly some helper functions that wrap other, more generic functions with some default parameters. Still, they're listed in the reference, and it's explicitly stated there that some "functions" may be implemented as macros for performance reasons. Gotta wonder if in 2020 compilers wouldn't do a better job at deciding what to inline and when.

Comment: Did you build a dart:ffi plugin for Lua? I'm interessed in that, but I need a binding to Lua 5.1. My main issue with the Lua packages on pub.dev are, that the use methods channels and not dart:ffi. They are also missing register functions, so I can call from Lua custom dart code.

Comment: sorry, actually not, had to postpone this project for a while